# How can I implement analytics.js to my page and send the tracking methods to my own backend

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, analytics, segment, analytics.js

Is it possible to handle the analytics.js library to send the events to my own backend instead of going through configured third party plugins? Or is there any way to implement a plugin with my own api, so it will send to my backend?

I tried importing analytics.js to my `index.html` and follow some instructions from the documentation, but to load the library, it says `analytics.load('YOUR_KEY')`, but for my case, I don´t think if this `YOUR_KEY` is necessary, since I would not like to implement a plugin.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I believe analytics.js is the legacy GA library. It does not support custom endpoints for tracking.

Try Matomo. It's open source and supports you hosting analytics on your own backend.